# Regex with repeated group in koa-router is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, regex, koa-router

I want to call an endpoint with a comma separated list, lets say I want to call with e.g.
"hey,you" or "hey,you,abc"

If I call with

> curl "http://localhost:8896/hey,you"

it is working with the following route:

```
router.get('/:id([a-z]{3},[a-z]{3})', (ctx) => {
  ctx.status = 200;
})
```

However this route is not working:

```
router.get('/:id([a-z]{3}(,[a-z]{3})*)', (ctx) => {
  ctx.status = 200;
})
```

I would expect this

> (,[a-z]{3})*

to allow a repeated subgroup with , and 3 chars.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/(^[a-z]{3}(?:,[a-z]{3})*$)/` to get the comma separated string, as a unique response, where you can split the results latter.

Alternatively, if you need regex to split them for you, you may use something like `/,?([a-z]{3}),?/g`. But I don't know how to enable the global flag in the routes, and it would also accept things like `,hey,you` or `hey,you,`.

However, [express route regex](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) uses it's own regex rules with [path-to-regexp package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) that doesn't allow catching groups `(?:)`, and then, you can not define any repetition pattern as you need.

So it looks like the only way to make repetitions is with `*` (zero or more) or `+` (one or more), after the key name, so we could use something like `/:id+([a-z]{3},?)` where you can enable strict, sensitive and end.

You can test your regex paths with the [Express Route Tester](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/).

So it would be something like:

```
router.get('/:id+([a-z]{3},?)', (ctx) => {
  ctx.status = 200;
})
```

You may need to post-process the id to remove the `,`.

Another alternative would be using a [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).

Comment: This is not working either. It returns a syntax error

`SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\/((?:[^\/]+?))\(\^\[a-z\]\{3\}(?:((?:?\:,[a-z]{3})(?:(?:?\:,[a-z]{3}))*))?\$\)(?:\/(?=$))?$/: Nothing to repeat`

However there should also be at least one comma in the list.

It's like koa-router doesn't support sub-groups.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was no familiar with the regex limitations of path-to-regexp package. I updated the response, hope it helps now.

Comment: If I use the updated answer and call with
_http://localhost:8896/hey,you_

the ctx params ends up like:
`{
  "0": "you",
  "id": "hey,"
}`

_http://localhost:8896/hey,you,hoo_ ends up like:
`{
  "0": "hoo",
  "id": "hey,you,"
}`

It's not quite as expected as I would expect all the params to come in id param.

Right now I will skip the regex part and do the check in the route.

Comment: Sorry I could be of more help. I would use the middleware, as this regex is really limited, and if there is a way around, I'm not aware of it.

Comment: Thanks for trying anyway. 
I didn't found any good middleware for koa doing this, so will use the workaround.